# BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request Python Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I´m getting the following error on python when I trying to do some scraping:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 26, in 
> signin2.fields["ctl06$txtParam_1"].value = '139210'
>
> File "C:\Users\Alvaro
> Pabon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line
> 781, in **getitem**
> raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
>
> BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a
> request that this server could not understand.

I provide the `html` and the `python` code, what am I doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```
    <form method="post" action="Default.aspx?IdControl=SolicitarReporteUC&amp;TipoProceso=G" id="Form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTE2MjczMjc4MQ9kFgICAw9kFgICBQ9kFgJmD2QWDgIBDxAPFgYeDkRhdGFWYWx1ZUZpZWxkBQpDb2RSZXBvcnRlHg1EYXRhVGV4dEZpZWxkBQdSZXBvcnRlHgtfIURhdGFCb3VuZGdkEBUBI0NlcnRpZmljYWRvIGRlIGhpc3RvcmlhIGxhYm9yYWwgRlBNFQEFMTAwOTUUKwMBZxYBZmQCAw9kFgJmD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIBDw9kFgIeB29uY2xpY2sFdmphdmFzY3JpcHQ6cmV0dXJuIEJ1c2NhckNvblBvc3RCYWNrKCdFbXBsZWFkb19WSVBQJywnQ29kRW1wbGVhZG8nLCdFbXBsZWFkbycsJycsJ2N0bDA2X3R4dFBhcmFtXzEnLCdjdGwwNl90eHREZXNjXzEnKTtkAgcPDxYCHgRUZXh0ZWRkAgkPEA8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWdkEBUBA1BERhUBA1BERhQrAwFnZGQCCw8PFgIeB0VuYWJsZWRnZGQCDQ8PFgIfBGVkZAIRDzwrAAsBAA8WCB4IRGF0YUtleXMWAB4LXyFJdGVtQ291bnQCAR4JUGFnZUNvdW50AgEeFV8hRGF0YVNvdXJjZUl0ZW1Db3VudAIBZBYCZg9kFgICAg9kFgxmD2QWAgIDDw8WAh4LTmF2aWdhdGVVcmwFOkRlZmF1bHQuYXNweD9JZENvbnRyb2w9UGV0aWNpb25lc1ZlclVDJkNvZFBldGljaW9uPTk4NDI0NjZkZAIBDw8WAh8EBQc5ODQyNDY2ZGQCAg8PFgIfBAUKMDQvMDcvMjAxN2RkAgMPDxYCHwQFLENlcnRpZmljYWRvIGRlIGhpc3RvcmlhIGxhYm9yYWwgRlBNKDEzOTIxMCwpZGQCBA8PFgIfBAUBVGRkAgUPDxYCHwQFCVRlcm1pbmFkb2RkZG9xWba643oqthJTATkgc95Acvr6oJVDDdMGc4QiUOHQ" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['Form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.Form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/peoploEL/WebResource.axd?d=Vo5dwRm0erdgUaaz932BKtVNZGJOgXKXcR91FZwwFfehyhj6Sl2EkKnl2mAONakSWUxeINyfjibWOjKY8z8OLswtutIQ6CR4NPqhOOhW3-c1&amp;t=635195493660000000" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var __cultureInfo = {"name":"es-CO","numberFormat":{"CurrencyDecimalDigits":2,"CurrencyDecimalSeparator":",","IsReadOnly":true,"CurrencyGroupSizes":[3],"NumberGroupSizes":[3],"PercentGroupSizes":[3],"CurrencyGroupSeparator":".","CurrencySymbol":"$","NaNSymbol":"NeuN","CurrencyNegativePattern":14,"NumberNegativePattern":1,"PercentPositivePattern":0,"PercentNegativePattern":0,"NegativeInfinitySymbol":"-Infinito","NegativeSign":"-","NumberDecimalDigits":2,"NumberDecimalSeparator":",","NumberGroupSeparator":".","CurrencyPositivePattern":2,"PositiveInfinitySymbol":"Infinito","PositiveSign":"+","PercentDecimalDigits":2,"PercentDecimalSeparator":",","PercentGroupSeparator":".","PercentSymbol":"%","PerMilleSymbol":"‰","NativeDigits":["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],"DigitSubstitution":1},"dateTimeFormat":{"AMDesignator":"a.m.","Calendar":{"MinSupportedDateTime":"\/Date(-62135578800000)\/","MaxSupportedDateTime":"\/Date(253402300799999)\/","AlgorithmType":1,"CalendarType":1,"Eras":[1],"TwoDigitYearMax":2029,"IsReadOnly":true},"DateSeparator":"/","FirstDayOfWeek":0,"CalendarWeekRule":0,"FullDateTimePattern":"dddd, dd\u0027 de \u0027MMMM\u0027 de \u0027yyyy hh:mm:ss tt","LongDatePattern":"dddd, dd\u0027 de \u0027MMMM\u0027 de \u0027yyyy","LongTimePattern":"hh:mm:ss tt","MonthDayPattern":"dd MMMM","PMDesignator":"p.m.","RFC1123Pattern":"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss \u0027GMT\u0027","ShortDatePattern":"dd/MM/yyyy","ShortTimePattern":"hh:mm tt","SortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy\u0027-\u0027MM\u0027-\u0027dd\u0027T\u0027HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss","TimeSeparator":":","UniversalSortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy\u0027-\u0027MM\u0027-\u0027dd HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss\u0027Z\u0027","YearMonthPattern":"MMMM\u0027 de \u0027yyyy","AbbreviatedDayNames":["dom","lun","mar","mié","jue","vie","sáb"],"ShortestDayNames":["do","lu","ma","mi","ju","vi","sá"],"DayNames":["domingo","lunes","martes","miércoles","jueves","viernes","sábado"],"AbbreviatedMonthNames":["ene","feb","mar","abr","may","jun","jul","ago","sep","oct","nov","dic",""],"MonthNames":["enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio","julio","agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre",""],"IsReadOnly":true,"NativeCalendarName":"calendario gregoriano","AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames":["ene","feb","mar","abr","may","jun","jul","ago","sep","oct","nov","dic",""],"MonthGenitiveNames":["enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio","julio","agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre",""]},"eras":[1,"d.C.",null,0]};//]]>
</script>

<script src="/peoploEL/ScriptResource.axd?d=oxaJQOalmF_Pc9FHyAFTk_k6TF1NEbUrjIYsB44pk6WCbYo_nSIw4yk5tC2xEtvEorNRA5gOfFsIU4ZnWzjKxobYxQm7qlMyDI-yMbMSd2l6ZDbJap8N8TY6mfiS7PCqS0ZD_N1nysIMDoEuJENdCQ2&amp;t=23c9c237" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]]>
</script>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__SCROLLPOSITIONX" id="__SCROLLPOSITIONX" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__SCROLLPOSITIONY" id="__SCROLLPOSITIONY" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAArkW6hVSYy1X/RA+Sj0CGQLGp+bdMCDYaJlV2GIWm9IvBdcfX0kLMsTvDhzcFP+5BCmu+5iWjvwd5K06ry8EbPN8eAu30BFMFNpn4fF9w5RD0sfx0Rt1Zoo22r6RgHWIEvbk+/Q0viP1b4fioHhV6vuLByhWnJD/fsZOTyD54nbDa+qASD48033XmTIh5CNr4axLA/MabVFryGhaiI+QVUeJtZhbNAXh60wJUXNyENePpp0PUjhju74p8tImEJGpMk=" />
</div>
            <TABLE id="Table1" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="80%" align="center"
                height="72%">
                <TR>
                    <TD height="25" vAlign="top" width="165" align="center"></TD>
                    <TD height="25" width="10"></TD>
                    <TD height="25" vAlign="top"></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD vAlign="top" width="165" align="center">
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="EstilosWeb.css">
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="EstilosWeb.css">
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 160px; HEIGHT: 64px" id="tMain" class="main" cellPadding="0" width="160">
    <TR vAlign="top">
        <TD id="NavTd">
            <DIV id="Nav">
                <H4 align="center">Menu
                    <table id="PanelIzquierdoUC1_htbCategorias" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0px;width:160px;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td><a id="PanelIzquierdoUC1_ConsultarLiquidacion" title="Consulta de Liquidación" href="Default.aspx?IdControl=ConsultaLiquidacionFltUC">Consultar Liquidación</a></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a id="PanelIzquierdoUC1_Reportes" title="Certificado Ing. y Ret." href="Default.aspx?IdControl=ReportesUC">Certificado Ing. y Ret.</a></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a id="PanelIzquierdoUC1_CambiarClave" title="Cambio de Clave" href="Default.aspx?IdControl=CambioClaveUC">Cambio de Clave</a></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a id="PanelIzquierdoUC1_ReportesGeneral" title="Reportes" href="Default.aspx?IdControl=SolicitarReporteUC&amp;TipoProceso=G">Reportes</a></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><a id="PanelIzquierdoUC1_CerrarSesion" title="Cerrar Sesion" href="Default.aspx?IdControl=CerrarSesionUC">Cerrar Sesion</a></td>
    </tr>
</table></H4>
            </DIV>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>

</TD>
                    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                    <TD vAlign="top">
                        
                        <div id="pnlCargaUserControl" style="width:100%;">
    
<LINK href="EstilosWeb.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        height: 26px;
        width: 36px;
    }
</style>
<TABLE class="FormaTabla" id="Table1" cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="1" width="300" border="0">
    <TR>
        <TD class="FormaEncabezado" colSpan="2">Reportes</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colSpan="2">
            <P align="center">&nbsp;</P>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colSpan="2"><select size="4" name="ctl06$lstReportes" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl06$lstReportes\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ctl06_lstReportes" class="FormaInfo" style="height:215px;width:564px;">
        <option selected="selected" value="10095">Certificado de historia laboral FPM</option>

    </select></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colSpan="2">Parametros</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD style="HEIGHT: 45px" colSpan="2"><table id="ctl06_tbParametros" rules="all" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Empleado</td><td><input name="ctl06$txtParam_1" type="text" value="139211" readonly="readonly" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl06$txtParam_1\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="ctl06_txtParam_1" Tabla="Empleado_VIPP" CodigoCampo="CodEmpleado" DescripcionCampo="Empleado" Condicion="" TipoDato="N" Parametro="Empleado" /><input type="submit" name="ctl06$btnParam_1" value="..." id="ctl06_btnParam_1" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled" onclick="javascript:return BuscarConPostBack(&#39;Empleado_VIPP&#39;,&#39;CodEmpleado&#39;,&#39;Empleado&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;ctl06_txtParam_1&#39;,&#39;ctl06_txtDesc_1&#39;);" style="width:25px;" /></td><td><input name="ctl06$txtDesc_1" type="text" value="JUAN DE LOS PALOTES" readonly="readonly" id="ctl06_txtDesc_1" style="width:250px;" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table></TD>
    </TR>   
    <TR>
        <TD class="style1">
            
                   
        </TD>
        <td>
         <P align="center"><select name="ctl06$ddlFormato" id="ctl06_ddlFormato" style="width:104px;">
        <option value="PDF">PDF</option>

    </select>&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="ctl06$btnAceptar" value="Aceptar" id="ctl06_btnAceptar" />     
         </P>
        </td>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colSpan="2">
            <P align="left"><span id="ctl06_lblMensaje" style="color:Red;font-family:Arial;"></span></P>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
<P>
    <input type="submit" name="ctl06$ButActualizar" value="Actualizar" id="ctl06_ButActualizar" /></P>
<P><table class="FormaGrid" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl06_dtgDatos" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>CodPeticion</td><td>FechaHora</td><td>Peticion</td><td>Estado</td><td>DetalleEstado</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                     <a id="ctl06_dtgDatos_ctl03_cmdVer" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl06$dtgDatos$ctl03$cmdVer&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Ver</a>
                    
                </td><td>9842466</td><td>04/07/2017</td><td>Certificado(139211,)</td><td>T</td><td>Terminado</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td colspan="6"><span>1</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table></P>



</div>
                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
```

**PYTHON:**

```
form2 = browser.get_form(id='Form1')
form2["ctl06$txtParam_1"].value = '139211'
form2["ctl06$txtDesc_1"].value = 'JUAN DE LOS POTES'
form2["ctl06$ddlFormato"].value = 'PDF'
form2["ctl06$lstReportes"].value = '10095'
form2["__EVENTTARGET"].value = 'ctl06$dtgDatos$ctl03$cmdVer'
form2["__EVENTARGUMENT"].value = ''
browser.submit_form(signin2)
```

Comment: what library are you using to submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

Use python request lib for that

Create Json and pass it through the headers and remember <__EVENTTARGET>
<__EVENTARGUMENT> This previous <> mention parameter always changing after few minute (based on website).

It Will easy if you use POST method and for before sending request check it in POSTMAN once.

```
        header = {

            "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txt_tradename": str(index),
            "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSearchTin": "",
            "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddl_dist": 2,
            "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnDlrSearch": "Search",
            "__EVENTVALIDATION": token.get("__EVENTVALIDATION", "")
            , "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": token.get("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"),
            "__VIEWSTATE": token.get("__VIEWSTATE")
        }
        try:
            req = requests.post(url, header)
```

Comment: Mrinal, the problem in this case is that the form has two action buttons and I have to decide which one to use.                     
    `browser.submit_form(signin2, submit=signin2["ctl06$btnAceptar"])